# Take the highest number from a text file and increment it by 1 as a var

Tags: powershell

I have a list of numbers in a txt file that i need to find the highest number and increment it by 1. That new number needs to be stored in the var $test so i can reuse it later on. When i try to run the code the following error occurs:

The '++' operator works only on numbers. The operand is a 'System.Object[]'.
At line:11 char:1
+ ++$test
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OperatorRequiresNumber

I've tried converting it into a INT but still no luck

```
$fileout = "c:\users\test\testout.txt"
$test = get-content -path $fileout | foreach {$PSItem -as [int32]}
$test++
```

Expected result - The largest number should be found in the file, it is then incremented by 1 and stored in the $test var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lee_Dailey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57386633/45375) correctly diagnoses your problem (`$test` receives an *array* of integers, and `++` cannot be applied to an an array - you're missing the step of finding the max.)

Let me complement it with a **LINQ-based solution** that is both concise and performs well:

```
$test = 1 + [Linq.Enumerable]::Max([int[]] (Get-Content $fileout))
```

- `Get-Content $fileout` returns the lines from file `$fileOut` as an array of strings.
- Cast `[int[]]` converts that string array to an array of integers.
- [`[Linq.Enumerable]::Max()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max) accepts a strongly typed collection of numbers and determines the max. among them.

  - Note how the LINQ `Max` method must be called as a static method on type `System.Linq.Enumerable`, because PowerShell as of v7 doesn't support *extension methods*; support for the latter is being discussed in [this RFC proposal](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-RFC/pull/86/files).

Answer (score 0):

your code was trying to increment the *entire collection* since you didn't do anything other than convert the items to `[int]`s. [*grin*] here's a way to do the job that trims away whitespace, removes everything *except* digits and the minus sign, sorts the results, and *finally* grabs the last one.

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
# every 3rd item has either leading or trailing whitespace [or both]
# some numbers have thousands delimiters [commas in this case]
$InStuff = @'
1
11
 2,000
33
+4
5 
666,666
7
 21 
-8
9
 0
100
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine

$HighestInt = $InStuff |
    ForEach-Object {
        # this trims away any leading/trailing  whitespace
        #     then it replaces anything other than a digit or a minus sign with nothing
        [int]($_.Trim() -replace '[^0-9-]')
        } |
    Sort-Object |
    Select-Object -Last 1

$HighestInt
```

output = `666666`

Comment: Note that you can cast your input array as-is to `[int[]]` - no need to manually trim whitespace, ,`+`, or `,` (PowerShell casts use the invariant culture, so `,` is always treated as the thousands group separator and effectively ignored, irrespective of the current culture).